# Can Eclipse (or any IDE) introduce type parameters to an existing type

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, refactoring

This is the exact opposite of [how can I remove generic type from class using refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440913/how-can-i-remove-generic-type-from-class-using-refactoring).

I want to introduce a type parameter to an interface. It is used quite extensively, so not very practical to do by hand. It is also widely used in import statements and JavaDoc, so a simple global string replace will not work very well either.

Edit:

I did try the "use parent type when possible" refactoring, but it understandably did not work very well at introducing type parameters.

Comment: I just tried this in intellij 12.1.3. It 'almost' worked, when I used shift-F6 on an interface and renamed it from `Foo` to `Foo<T>`, the IDE gave an error. But if you exit IDEA directly after typing `Foo<T>`, and  without hitting enter, it at least changed all the interface references in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IntelliJ, you can use the "Change Signature" refactoring.  Given this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyContainer container = new MyContainer("hello!");
    String val = container.get();
    System.out.println(val);
}

class MyContainer {
    final Object value;

    MyContainer(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    Object get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I right-clicked on `MyContainer`, then chose Refactor->Change Signature...  From here, you can introduce a type parameter `T`.  You need to give a default concrete type for `T`.  Most of the time, to preserve existing code, this would be `Object`; but it depends on the class you're changing.  For example, if `MyContainer` above used `Number` instead of `Object`, the equivalent of the new erasure type would be `Number`.  But you would also need to declare `T extends Number` in that case.

When I finish this, I get the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyContainer<Object> container = new MyContainer<Object>("hello!");
    String val = (String) container.get();
    System.out.println(val);
}

class MyContainer<T> {
    final Object value;

    MyContainer(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    Object get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now you can start to use `T` in `MyContainer`, and by looking at the files that `IntelliJ` changed, you can start to see where you need to look to start filling in the correct type arguments (since all auto-generated type parameters will be `Object`).

Comment: Verified in IntelliJ. Thanks a lot! I also found out, you can put `?` in the default value box which exactly meets my need.